# How to animate CCProgressTimer sprite?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

is there a way to animate CCProgressTimer sprite?
I tried but it doesn’t work :(

```
if (timeCountdown <= 10) {


    CCAnimation *animation = [[CCAnimation alloc] init];
    [animation addSpriteFrameWithFilename:@"time-bar.png"];
    [animation addSpriteFrameWithFilename:@"time-bar-white.png"];
    [animation setDelayPerUnit:0.02f];
    [animation setLoops:1];
    [progressTimer.sprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]]];
    }
```

When timeCountdown <= 10, I want progress bar flashes forever.
Thanks.

EDIT: Find a solution, but I don’t know why lol
just remove progressTimer.sprite from parent, run action, and add it to layer again:

```
if (timeCountdown <= 10) {
        int n = [progressTimer.sprite numberOfRunningActions];
        if (n == 0) {
            [time_bar removeFromParent];
            CCAnimation *animation = [[CCAnimation alloc] init];
            [animation addSpriteFrameWithFilename:@"time-bar.png"];
            [animation addSpriteFrameWithFilename:@"time-bar-white.png"];
            [animation setDelayPerUnit:0.02f];
            [animation setRestoreOriginalFrame:YES];
            id repeatAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]];
            [time_bar runAction:repeatAction];
            [self addChild:time_bar];
        }
    }
    else {
        [time_bar stopAllActions];
        [time_bar setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"time-bar.png"]];


    }
```

EDIT2: Just add the sprite to layer, set Visible to NO, and run aciton. This is a trick because sprite can't run action if it is not a child of layer.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the color property of the sprite. Or periodically change its visible state.

Comment: I see. But how to run action forever? Please check my new code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
//[animation setLoops:1];
[progressTimer stopAllActions];
[progressTimer.sprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]]];
```